# Force EclipseLink to use discriminator column in delete statement

Tags: inheritance, eclipselink, jpa-2.0

I'm using JPA/EclipseLink. I defined a superclass named Parameter

```
@Entity
@Table(name="parameter")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="type",discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING,length=64)
@DiscriminatorValue(value="fr.itce.babel.entity.Parameter")
public class Parameter {
    @Id
    String code;

    String value;
...
}
```

And two other entities inheriting

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value="fr.itce.babel.entity.Line")
public class Line extends Parameter {

}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value="fr.itce.babel.entity.Phase")
public class Phase extends Parameter {

}
```

When I'm selecting all "Line", the query generated is

```
select code, value from parameter where type = ?
```

with type = 'fr.itce.babel.entity.Line'

It works for me.

But when deleting a Line entity, I get something like this

```
delete from parameter where code = ?
```

Yuck... it doesn't use the discriminator column and so delete all entities with the same code event if it is a Phase...

How can I force the use of the discriminator column in my delete query?

Answer (score 1):

code is the Id, and unique, so there should not be an issue?

You could force the type to be included using a custom deleteQuery on the DescriptorQueryManager, using a DescriptorCustomizer, but I can't see I reason for this as code is the Id.  You may also wish to use optimistic locking (@Version) if you are concerned of users deleting the incorrect object.

Answer (score 0):

These entities are in one table where key column is *code*. Because it is a key, it is unique and there is no possibility to have more than one entity with same value of *code*. EclipseLink is aware about type of Entity so there is no need to have discriminator in delete statement.